# How do I "link time" to join a Hellfire Citadel group?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

When trying to join groups using the group finder, I often see people asking me to "link time". I presume they're asking me to add a link to "Time is a flat circle" in my join request... but I can't use the usual click / ctrl+click method to get the achievement into the window.

What should I be doing?

Comment: Do you have any addons that may intercept the control click? (Does it work for linking other things?)

Comment: Linking is working for other things, yeah. (whether it's ctrl or shift or whatever I can't remember straight away...). I'd never thought to right-click on a group so never saw the "whisper leader" thing there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you have to do is request to join the group and then send the raid leader a tell with the achievement link.

Answer (score 1):

The normal action to link an achievement when you have chat open is <kbd>shift</kbd>+click.